# Can a specific and generic website address be used with a Wildcard SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl-certificate

My group is moving from HTTP to HTTPS with using a wildcard SSL certificate. In the HTTP environment we were able to access an intranet site using the generic site name (website.com) and the specific name (website.agency.state.xx.us).

The wildcard certificate is allowing us to use the specific name currently. Can we configure it to also use the generic / short site name?

Answer (score 0):

You could have two certificates for each domain name and resolve the names to the same server